# Repair pads on PCB

Tags: pcb, repair, damage, pad

I've accidentally used too much force on the board while trying to remove a flex connector and so I've removed a lot of PCB pads as well (see image).

[image: photo of damaged PCB]

I have a new flex connector, but I do not have any PCB pads, except for a tiny part of each of them that still exist.

Can you please advise as to what I should do next?

I was thinking that I'll prepare straight pins on the flex connector and try to solder each pin to the tiny part that still exists of each PCB pad.

Do you have a better idea?

Comment: I'm pretty good with a soldering iron, but if I did that to a board I'd just kick myself in the backside then start looking for a place to buy a new board.

Comment: Looks like you've got via's/traces nearby for all the broken pads. I've repaired such things in the past by scraping away the soldermask on the ground so you can solder the new connectors shield pins to it but placing it further toward the front of the board. That gives you room to attach thin pieces of enameled wire between the via's and the new connector. You'll probably need a microscope, fine soldering equipment and a steady hand.

Comment: @JRE, totally agree. I already kicked myself twice for that. :-\

Comment: @Unimportant, makes total sense. Thanks a lot!